# Selenium: Can't SendKeys() to an item that was below the visible window but was made visible by Click()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this problem with a text field that is *visible* at the time of the SendKeys.  I'm using IEDriverServer.exe and C#.

Here's how I can reproduce the problem:

The text field in question is visible in the window but you have to scroll down to see it.  To scroll down I click on the element using code like this:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("…"));
element.Click();
```

This scrolls the window down and makes the text field visible.

But when I try to send text to now-visible window:

```
element.SendKeys("blah");
```

I get the exception:

> When_applicant_enters_application.Should_be_instantly_approved_on_external threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed

How can I fix or workaround this problem?

Selenium version: 2.32.1
OS: Windows 7
Browser: IE
Browser version: 9.0.15

Comment: Try using `element.clear()` before `element.sendKeys()` and let us know the result.

Comment: did you try to find and use the arrow to "scroll down" the page until  you see the element that you want to manipulate ?

Comment: To have any hope of being able to help, one will need a page of HTML that demonstrates the issue. Without that, all else is speculation.

Comment: I've been trying the FirefoxDriver as a possible workaround, but it has different behavior from the InternetExplorerDriver.  Very aggravating.  I'm aware that there are differences between IE and FF but I think the details of simple selections should be pushed below the API level. element.Click() brings element into focus just like Clear() or a manual scroll. There's no way in Selenium to select the scroll that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written code demonstrating the problem and submitted it to the Selenium tech support volunteers.

The full discussion is at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5620
but the take-home is:

```
// Doesn't work
// driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
// driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"D:\CGY\selenium\Bug5620\Bug5620\Bug5620.htm");

// Works
// driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"D:\CGY\selenium\Bug5620\Bug5620\Bug5620.htm");

// Works
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://localhost:8080/Bug5620/"); // Hosted on Tomcat
```

so there may be a problem that possibly involves IE, IE security settings, Visual Studio local servers and/or the IE Driver. This may not even be a code problem, but something that needs to be documented, since other people are apparently running into the problem.

I don't know where the problem is exactly but I do have a work-around at this point, which is to use the Firefox Driver.

Thanks for your help, Jim.  If you find out a better way of dealing with the problem, please add an answer here for the other folks.

Comment: "Selenium tech support." That's funny. You realize that the Selenium project is open source, and is completely a volunteer project, right? There isn't any "tech support department," just a bunch of volunteers who develop the software and try to help out where they can.

Comment: No offense meant, I hope none was taken.  Thank you for your considerable service to the Selenium open-source community.